# Library for converting python string to c style code

Tags: python, c, formatting

need help with styling.

```
c_code = """
//This is an auto-generated file, please don't edit.
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
return 0;
}
"""
file = open('main.c', 'w')
file.write(c_code)
file.close()
```

I have this simple code that will generate a c file from a python string. Is there a way to write the code after formatting in c style to the file? Instead of me explicitly indenting all code in the string?

So instead of this:

```
    //This is an auto-generated file, please don't edit.
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(){
    return 0;
    }
```

I need this:

```
//This is an auto-generated file, please don't edit.
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

**Is there a library that can do this?** Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a formatter like https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html on the genrated file.

Comment: Please reread the [Ask] page.  This question is off-topic for SO because it is "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more —
This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers."

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sure, Thanks. But is there a better platform for such questions?